# Conformal mappings and diffusion processes with boundary condition

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have a question on a relation between conformal mappings and diffusion processes with boundary condition.

Let $D_1$ be a smooth simply connected domain of $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}$. This may be unbounded.

We can define the **normally** reflecting Brownian motion $X$ on $\bar{D_1}$. We can also describe the Skorohod equation. The generator is the Laplacian $\Delta$ on $D_1$ with Neumann boundary condition.

Let $D_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an another smooth simply connected domain.
Let $\Psi:D_1 \to D_2$ be a conformal mapping. 
We also assume that $\Psi$ is extended to a homeomorphism from $\bar{D_1} \to \bar{D_2}$ and $\Psi(\partial D_1)=\partial D_2$ (I do not know if this assumption is necessary. Please tell me if it is unnecessary.).

By using this map, we can make the change of variable: $ D_1 \ni (\rho,z) \mapsto (r,w) \in D_2$, where $r=\text{Re}\Psi(\rho,z)$ and $z=\text{Im} \Psi(\rho,z)$.

In $(r,w)$-coordinate, $\Delta$ does not  take the form $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w^2}$. In $(r,w)$-coordinate, $\Delta$ becomes an another diffusion operator. We denote by $\mathcal{L}$ the operator.

My question is as follows:

- Does the diffusion process $\Psi(X)$ correspond to the operator $\mathcal{L}$ with Neumann boundary condition on $\partial D_2$?

You will think that this is trivial. But I do not know how to justify these results.

Should I prove that the diffusion processe determined by $\mathcal{L}$ (with Neumann boundary condition) and the diffusion process $\Psi(X)$ coincide?

**ADD:**

$X$ satisfies the following SDE:
$X_t=x+B_t+\int_{0}^{t}\nu(X_s)\,dL_s$. Here, $\{L_t\}$ denotes the boundary local time of $X$ and $\nu$ the normal inward unit vector on $\partial D_1$. I guess that $\Psi(X)$ is a time-changed reflecting Brownian motion on $D_2$.

Let $u=\text{Re}(\Psi)$, $v=\text{Im}(\Psi)$. Note that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic function on $D_1$. Then,
\begin{align*}
u(X_t)&=u(x)+\int_{0}^{t}\nabla u (X_s)\,dX_s +(1/2)\int_{0}^{t}\Delta u(X_s)\,ds  \\
&=u(x)+\int_{0}^{t}\nabla u(X_s)\,dB_s+\int_{0}^{t}(\nabla u,\nu)(X_s)\,dL_s.
\end{align*}
Similarly, it holds that
\begin{align*}
v(X_t)
&=v(x)+\int_{0}^{t}\nabla v(X_s)\,dB_s+\int_{0}^{t}(\nabla v,\nu)(X_s)\,dL_s.
\end{align*}
By the CR-equation, it is easy to see that 
\begin{align*}
&<\int_{0}^{\cdot}\nabla u(X_s)\,dB_s>_t=<\int_{0}^{\cdot}\nabla v(X_s)\,dB_s>_t=\int_{0}^{t}|\Psi'(B_s)|^2\,ds \\
&<\int_{0}^{\cdot}\nabla u(X_s)\,dB_s,\int_{0}^{\cdot}\nabla v(X_s)\,dB_s>_t=0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the martingale part of $\Psi(X)$ is a time-changed (two-dimensional) Brownian motion.

What the next term will be?:
\begin{equation*}
(\int_{0}^{t}(\nabla u,\nu)(X_s)\,dL_s, \int_{0}^{t}(\nabla u,\nu)(X_s)\,dL_s).
\end{equation*}

**ADD2:**

I found a related result. In Chapter 5 of this book [CF](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/9628.html), the authors identify the Dirichlet form of $\Psi(X)$.

Comment: The approach based on Dirichlet forms seems to be the right one. If the boundaries are Lipschitz, the conformal map $\Psi$ automatically extends to a homeomorphism between the the closures, and further smoothness of boundaries implies further smoothness of $\Psi$ on the boundary. This easily proves that composition with $\Psi$ preserves the Sobolev space $H^1(D_i)$, and as you point out, the Dirichlet form of $\Psi(X)$ is the same as that of the reflecting Brownian motion in $D_2$, time-changed according to $|\Psi'|^2$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for your reply. I understood.